# bash: sdkmanager: command not found (chrome os linux)

Tags: linux, software-installation, android

I tried to install Android SDK Command-Line Tools:

- unzipped `commandlinetools-linux-9477386_latest.zip`
- made directory `a/cmdline-tools/latest` and put there command line tools files

After I tried to start working with it in the terminal.
my commands:

```
$ cd a/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/
/a/cmdline-tools/latest/bin$ sdkmanager --list
```

output error was

```
-bash: sdkmanager: command not found
```

Could you make a hint about my mistake in installation or in using it?

```
kaniktree@penguin:~/a/cmdline-tools/latest/bin$ ls apkanalyzer avdmanager lint profgen retrace screenshot2 sdkmanager 
kaniktree@penguin:~/a/cmdline-tools/latest/bin$ ./sdkmanager -bash: ./sdkmanager: Permission denied 
kaniktree@penguin:~/a/cmdline-tools/latest/bin$ sudo ./sdkmanager 
sudo: ./sdkmanager: command not found
```

Comment: As you're in the directory, does `ls` show `sdkmanager`? If yes, does command `./sdkmanager` start it?

Comment: kaniktree@penguin:~/a/cmdline-tools/latest/bin$ ls
apkanalyzer  avdmanager  lint  profgen  retrace  screenshot2  sdkmanager
kaniktree@penguin:~/a/cmdline-tools/latest/bin$ ./sdkmanager
-bash: ./sdkmanager: Permission denied
kaniktree@penguin:~/a/cmdline-tools/latest/bin$ sudo ./sdkmanager
sudo: ./sdkmanager: command not found

Comment: In general SE sites aren't discussion boards. If you're asked for clarification or more info, you should [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/735638/edit) your question to answer, not comment. That way everything relevant is immediately available for the community. I edited the question now, but it will only show up after my edit is verified. You can wait, or you can add it yourself now. I'd recommend taking the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and checking Asking- and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how these sites work.